# Change str_replace() in loop to single preg_replace() call?

Tags: php, regex

How do you change this to a `preg_replace()` equivalent (without using a loop)?

Note:  `$text` is utf-8.

```
  do $text = str_replace("* *", "*", $text, $totRepla); while ($totRepla);
```

Comment: Please provide a text example.

Comment: thaks to the one that change the subject. I was afraid about an horible google indexing top rank on a tribial and poorly formulated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the regexp pattern to match an arbitrary long `* * * * * *` is

```
/(\* )*\*/
```

Please add the rest of the code yourself, I don't have PHP handy right now to provide a full code snippet.

Comment: thanks i will use:  /(\* )+\*/  all other exposed solutions, do not reduce multiple ocurences to just one.

Comment: Would you try to benchmark your initial solution against regex one? It's interesting which runs faster :D

Comment: I'm sure it depends on how match consecutive asterisks do the $text have.  I bet regex is more eficient (cos compilated) with more than 10 on the input string.  If you write the code I run it on my server also.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, String functions are much more efficient then regex, I see no reason using regex if you have a working solution using str_replace.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

see documentation:

> If you don't need fancy replacing
>   rules (like regular expressions), you
>   should always use this function
>   instead of preg_replace().

Comment: `str_replace()` isn't necessarily more efficient if it's used in a `do ... while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('/\* \*/', '*', $totRepla);
```

Comment: That will still require the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

The PCRE equivalent of that is:

```
$text = preg_replace('~(?:[*] )+[*]~', '*', $text);
```

Your code suggests that you have no interest in knowing how many replacements occurred, so you don't need the `$totRepla` variable. However, if I am wrong, this is the way to get that count:

```
$text = preg_replace('~(?:[*] )+[*]~', '*', $text, -1, $totRepla);
```